# regex repetitive pattern with monetary amount

Tags: php, regex

`(?:[.,]?\d{3})*` this is a part of a monetary amount pattern which match the thousand separator and the 3 digits after. The thousand separator can either be `.`, `,` or nothing

But how to make it repetitive? If the first thousand separator is `.` then the rest should also be `.`

Comment: Why are you parsing money values with a regex instead of using PHP's built-in parsing libs?

Comment: @dai do you have a link to docs?

Comment: Also, if you intend to support both `.` and `,` as digit-grouping chars, then you need to think about how you can detect and correctly handle the radix point (which will be the _opposite_ of the digit-grouping char).

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php

Comment: Do your `monetary amount`s include decimals? (i.e. `1.234,56` for one thousand two hundred thirty four and fifty six cents)  If they do not, then just replace all '.' and ',' with '', and use normal formatting.

Comment: This question would be more complete if it had a battery of sample strings which represent realistic data from your project.  Then users wouldn't need to ask if you have any decimal places in your strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a capture group with a repeating backreference:

```
^(?:\d{4,}|\d{1,3}(?:([,.])\d{3}(?:\1\d{3})*)?)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `\d{4,}` Match 4 or more digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{1,3}` Match 1-3 digits
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `([,.])\d{3}` capture either a `.` or comma in group 1
    - `(?:\1\d{3})*` Optionally repeat the backreference to group 1 (the same char) followed by 3 digits
  - `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional (to also match 1-3 digits)
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aR2Y2P/1).

Comment: Why not atomically match `\d+` in the first branch?

Comment: @mickmackusa You can do that when using anchors indeed, I have used it here so that if you change it to word boundaries you don't get shorter partial matches because the `\d+` will then match first. But in that case you can also turn the alternatives around like https://regex101.com/r/w0SvgF/1

Answer (score 0):

Take it block by block: the begining the middle and the end.  Then use a or to match the numbers < 1000.

`^((\d{1,3}[.,]){,2}(\d{3}[,.])*(\d{3})|(\d{1,3}))$`

(This works with python regex on this tool: https://regex101.com/)

For PHP I had to modify it like this:

`^(\d{1,3}|(\d{1,3}[.,])+(\d{3}[.,])*\d{3})$`